# value is not passed to controller

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, post, serialization

i have a problem with passing values to the controller(jave) from javascript file after serialising the entries. when i run in debug mode its passing values to the controller but if its run straight away then its not passed. i first serilzed the values entered in the form and then post to the controller. any ideas please... the code is as follows function

```
submitSearch() {        
    var searchParams = $("#search-filters, #keyword-desktop-filters, #keyword-mobile-filters").serialize();     

    alert(searchParams);                
    $.ajax({        
        url: 'search?' + searchParams,              
        type: 'POST',           
        success: function (msg) {                 
            alert("hai");             
        },             
        error: function (xhr) {                 
            alert("kooyi");             
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: seems like you need to pass `data` object with your search parameters instead of concatenating them to url

Comment: like this: `data: { "search-filters": "123", "keyword-desktop-filters": "Boston" , ... }`

Comment: @Cherniv, why not post that as an answer before someone else does and takes your points?

Comment: @DerekHenderson because i didn't found in jquery's `.ajax`  specification that `POST` requires `data` parameter

Comment: @Cherniv, good point, but you know that POST doesn't append a string to the url the way GET does.  And someone is bound to post the exact same thing anyway. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass your search parameters like `data` parameter in your `.ajax` function settings object. Here the example:

```
 $.ajax({        
        url: 'search' ,              
        type: 'POST',
        data:  $("#search-filters, #keyword-desktop-filters, #keyword-mobile-filters").serialize(),      
        success: function (msg) {                 
            alert("hai");             
        },             
        error: function (xhr) {                 
            alert("kooyi");             
        }   
    });
```

And here is `.ajax` method' API: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @alenjoseph check out your `#search-filters, #keyword-desktop-filters, #keyword-mobile-filters` fields . what errors it outputs?

Comment: it doesnt show any errors...when i runs it in debug mode its passing values to the controller. but when i run in straight away its not passing...values are null...@chemiv

Comment: @alenjoseph when exactly you send it ? on submit button click?

Comment: there is a search option in the form with filters(check boxes). so when i click the search button its suppose to pass all the selected filters' values to the controller. its passing when run on debug mode. but its not passing when run straight away. values appears to be null in the controller. @Cherniv

Comment: @alenjoseph before you send it , try to output this : `$("#search-filters, #keyword-desktop-filters, #keyword-mobile-filters").serialize()` and see if object includes the data or not. of it does then it means that data get lost somewhere after being send

Comment: i did find that the data is serialized and the output shows the values. the values are lost only when i run this not in debug mode.

Comment: @alenjoseph so  i don't know. you also tagged it "java" so may be it is some server-side problem